# nmcli: Select BSSID when two access points have the same SSID

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm having trouble getting `nmcli` to connect the right access point when there are two with the same SSID. Ideally Network-Manager should connect to the one with the strongest signal, but it always seems to connect to the same one. I can't even force it to connect to the one I want by specifying the BSSID:

```
$ nmcli -f in-use,ssid,bssid,signal,rate,bars  dev wifi
IN-USE  SSID                       BSSID              SIGNAL  RATE        BARS 
        InternodeAC79C7            20:B0:01:AC:79:C7  92      130 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆█ 
        InternodeAC79C7-5G         22:B0:01:AC:79:CF  92      405 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆█ 
*       InternodeAC79C7            24:65:11:64:BA:93  72      270 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆_ 
$ nmcli device wifi connect 20:B0:01:AC:79:C7
Device 'wlp0s20f3' successfully activated with 'f1c36a2e-8fb0-4f88-95a7-40b9ddc32056'.
$ nmcli -f in-use,ssid,bssid,signal,rate,bars  dev wifi
IN-USE  SSID                       BSSID              SIGNAL  RATE        BARS 
        InternodeAC79C7            20:B0:01:AC:79:C7  92      130 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆█ 
        InternodeAC79C7-5G         22:B0:01:AC:79:CF  89      405 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆█ 
*       InternodeAC79C7            24:65:11:64:BA:93  62      270 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆_
```

Notice that Network-Manager is still connected to `24:65:11:64:BA:93`.

### Other possibly relevant set up info

- I'm running Debian Testing bullseye/sid
- Kernel version

  ```
  $ uname -a
  Linux binky 5.8.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.8.10-1 (2020-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- Contents of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/InternodeAC79C7.nmconnection`

  ```
  [connection]
  id=InternodeAC79C7
  uuid=f1c36a2e-8fb0-4f88-95a7-40b9ddc32056
  type=wifi
  interface-name=wlp0s20f3
  permissions=user:dcpurton:;
  timestamp=1601538860

  [wifi]
  mac-address-blacklist=
  mode=infrastructure
  seen-bssids=20:B0:01:AC:79:C7;24:65:11:64:BA:93;
  ssid=InternodeAC79C7

  [wifi-security]
  key-mgmt=wpa-psk
  psk=*****

  [ipv4]
  dns-search=
  method=auto

  [ipv6]
  addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
  dns-search=
  ip6-privacy=0
  method=auto

  [proxy]
  ```
- Wireless adaptor

  ```
  $ sudo lspci -v
  00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
      Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
      Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 6
      Memory at c9738000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
      Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
      Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
      Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
      Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
      Capabilities: [100] Null
      Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
      Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
      Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
      Kernel modules: iwlwifi
  ```
- Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad X390 20Q0

Comment: Have you tried issuing an `nmcli connection down InternodeAC79C7` command first and then `nmcli device wifi connect 20:B0:01:AC:79:C7` ?

Comment: @Krackout, same result. It still connects to `24:65:11:64:BA:93`.

Answer (score 11):

It seems there are two issues.

1. The `bssid` parameter of `nmcli` does not actually do what I expect. It's only used to select the SSID, and isn't passed to `wpa_supplicant`. See [issue #465](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/465)
2. NetworkManager doesn't seem to pick the AP with the strongest signal. It always connects to the same one no matter what (for me). See [issue #474](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/474). I guess possibly these two issues are related.

It is possible to use `wpa_cli` to switch access points:

```
$ sudo wpa_cli list_networks
Selected interface 'wlp0s20f3'
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0   InternodeAC79C7 any [CURRENT]
$ sudo wpa_cli bssid 0 20:B0:01:AC:79:C7
Selected interface 'wlp0s20f3'
OK
$ sudo wpa_cli reassociate
Selected interface 'wlp0s20f3'
OK
$ sudo wpa_cli list_networks
Selected interface 'wlp0s20f3'
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0   InternodeAC79C7 20:b0:01:ac:79:c7   [CURRENT]
$ nmcli -f in-use,ssid,bssid,signal,rate,bars  dev wifi
IN-USE  SSID                       BSSID              SIGNAL  RATE        BARS 
*       InternodeAC79C7            20:B0:01:AC:79:C7  92      130 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆█ 
        InternodeAC79C7-5G         22:B0:01:AC:79:CF  92      405 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆█ 
        InternodeAC79C7            24:65:11:64:BA:93  72      270 Mbit/s  ▂▄▆_
```

If I use NetworkManager to reconnect, it reverts back to `24:65:11:64:BA:93`.